# Communicating with server javaEE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I am trying to create a web page using JavaEE

I have created a new web project in netbeans.
It has generated a typical html page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But lets say I want to print information from the server. I created class

```
@Stateless
@Path("/")
public class NewClass {
    public String name = "MyName";
    @GET
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

with route "/" for testing. I want to print the `name` variable inside the page. I have tried using

```
<div>#{NewClass.getName()}</div>
```

in html but it just printed  `"#{NewClass.getName()}"`

What is the right way to do it? Is ( using `.html` ) the only way to do it using ajax?

/////

I have tried generating JSP

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        "#{NewClass.getName()}"
    </h:body>
</html>
```

But it just prints `""`

I cannot find any good resource for this.

Comment: JSP is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @MouseEvent I tried it without good result , i will update question soon ,

Comment: Try `<% NewClass.getName(); %>`

Comment: @Hackerman This throws parsing erro in xhtml file

Comment: What is the application server you are using and which version?

Comment: Ok, my jsp knowledge it's a bit outdated...try with `<% NewClass testClass = NewClass(); out.println(testClass.getName());%>`

Comment: @Hackerman, this is creating a new instance and using it.
It has nothing to do with having Ajax.
Johnyb, if the objective is to use Ajax, then you have to use Ajax either from HTML or JSP. If using AJAX is not the objective, then use Hackerman's latest comment

Comment: The objective is not to use Ajax , the objective is to print data from server. Preferably without ajax. I am using glassfish 4.4

Comment: @Johnyb I highly recommend reading this RESTful web services tutorial from TutorialsPoint.com here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_statelessness.htm

Comment: Just for the record, my last comment do not use ajax....is just server side rendering

Comment: If you are using a JSP to print the data, either statically without the class or using the class instance, then you are already on the server side.
BUT to truly separate the logic of rendering the display from the logic used to get the data, then one of the ways to go is Ajax.

Comment: @Johnyb Did you try the last comment from @Hackerman? I would change it a little bit to: `<% NewClass test = new NewClass(); %> <%= test.getName() %>`